# How to run thread in class method?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
class TestMgr{
    public:
            std::condition_variable mSubCond;
            static TestMgr & GetMgr() {
                    static TestMgr *Mgr = nullptr;
                    if (Mgr == nullptr) {
                            Mgr = new TestMgr();
                    }
                    return *Mgr;
            }
    };
    class CAL{
    public:
            std::mutex mtx1;
            std::mutex mtx2;
            std::thread threads1;
            std::thread threads2;
            int cum;
            int bum;
            int ID;
            CAL(int i){
                    ID = i;
                    cum = 0;
                    bum = 0;
                    threads1 = std::thread(&CAL::add, this);
                    threads2 = std::thread(&CAL::sub, this);
    
            }
            void add() {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Lck(mtx1);
                    std::cout << "add is waiting!" << std::endl;
                    TestMgr::GetMgr().mSubCond.wait(Lck);
                    while (true)
                    {
                            cum = cum + 1;
                            std::cout << "ID:" << ID << ", add:cum=" << cum << std::endl;
                            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    }
            }
            void sub(){    
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Lck(mtx2);
                    std::cout << "sub is waiting!" << std::endl;
                    TestMgr::GetMgr().mSubCond.wait(Lck);
                    while (true){
                            bum = bum - 1;
                            std::cout << "ID:" << ID << ", sub:bum=" << cum << std::endl;
                            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
                    }
            }
    };
    
    int main(){
            CAL TEST1(1);
            CAL TEST2(2);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
            TestMgr::GetMgr().mSubCond.notify_all();
            TEST1.threads1.join();
            TEST1.threads2.join();
            TEST2.threads1.join();
            TEST2.threads2.join();
            return 0;
    }
```

With the above code, I can't get the expected result under Linux with GCC. But it works fine under Windows. Can anyone help take a look and help explain that?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to identify what "the expected result" is, what actual result you get instead, and how that is wrong.

Comment: You have way too many errors. Everything is completely wrong. Go read/watch some C++ tutorials on multithreading: mutexes, condition_variable, and atomics.

Comment: 'join' is a good choice to coordinate a specific thread interaction ... the main thread will wait for each thread in sequence.  HOWEVER, it appears that the threads will not complete (infinite loop).  Thus, it appears that your main thread will suspend, waiting forever for something that will not occur. The threads, on the other hand, continue to run forever ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestMgr::GetMgr()` is not safe for multithreading, but is called concurrently (In `CAL::add()`from all 4 worker-threads).

Change it to the simpler

```
static TestMgr & GetMgr() {
    static TestMgr Mgr = TestMgr();
    return Mgr;
}
```

And it will be.